# Смысл выражения НЕ ОСТАВЛЯТЬ ПО СЕБЕ СЛЕДОВ

Tags: значение-слов

Наткнулся на выражение *не оставлять **по себе** следов*:

> Как жаль, что Грибоедов не оставил своих записок! Написать его
> биографию было бы делом его друзей; но замечательные люди исчезают у
> нас, **не оставляя по себе следов**. Мы ленивы и нелюбопытны...
>
> *Александр Сергеевич Пушкин,*
> *Путешествие в Арзрум во время похода 1829 года*

Как следует его понимать и является ли оно в настоящий момент употребимым?

Answer (score 2):

***Не оставляя по себе следов*** — это ***не оставляя после себя следов***, предлог ПО со значением времени (сравнить: *по окончании школы — после окончания школы*).

Из словаря:

**По себе.** 1. По своим силам, вкусам или требованиям. -2. После своего отъезда; после своей смерти. **Оставить по себе добрую память.**

Форма **по себе** с временным значение в основном используется **в устойчивых выражениях**: *оставить по себе память, оставить по себе след.*

Примеры:

Людям так хотелось **оставить по себе** хоть какую-нибудь память… [Д. С. Лихачев. Воспоминания (1995)]

Иначе говоря, университетская библиотека Рикке убедила нас, как много может сделать один человек и сколь значителен **след, который он в состоянии оставить по себе на земле.** [С. А. Дангулов. Танге (1981)]

**Примечание**

В современном языке предлог ПО в основном управляет  **дательным** падежом (например: каждый выбирает по себе…), но раньше он использовался и в других падежах.

До настоящего времени сохранилась форма **предложного** падежа со значением **времени** (по приезде, по окончании, по истечении) и форма **предложного** падежа с **изъяснительным** значением  (скучать по вас).

Эти формы падежного управления можно отнести к постепенно устаревающим.